# Performance is affected when EF uses ROW_NUMBER() for ordering and paging

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have an `Entity` view in my database and an `Entity` class in code that represents the view. To get result for a certain page I am doing this:

```cs
var result = await dbContext.Entity
    .OrderByDescending(e => e.CreatedOn)
    .ThenByDescending(e => e.Id)
    .Skip((currentPage - 1) * itemsPerPage)
    .Take(itemsPerPage)
    .ToListAsync();
```

For the first page of 50 items (`currentPage = 1`, `itemsPerPage = 50`) EF generates the following:

```sql
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[OrderId] AS [Id], 
    [Extent1].[Number] AS [CreatedOn], 
    ...
    FROM [dbo].[Entity] AS [Extent1]
    ORDER BY row_number() OVER (ORDER BY [Extent1].[CreatedOn] DESC, [Extent1].[Id] DESC)
    OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 50 ROWS ONLY
```

The problem is that the query is executing quite long. And that's why I tried  without row_number() and it was faster, and I got same results:

```sql
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[OrderId] AS [Id], 
    [Extent1].[Number] AS [CreatedOn], 
    ...
    FROM [dbo].[Entity] AS [Extent1]
    ORDER BY [Extent1].[CreatedOn] DESC, [Extent1].[Id] DESC
    OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 50 ROWS ONLY
```

So, my questions are:
1) Why is row_number() used here in general?
    2) Is there any why force EF not to use it in this query?

**UPDATE:** Adding clustered index on the table which view is using helped to improve performance. Thanks!

Comment: 1. It is used because of skip and take. 2. Do not use skip/take

Comment: If you really want to improve the query you need to profile it. You can do that by viewing the execution plan and then determine why it is slow. Do a search on Query Execution Plan Sql Server to get started.

Comment: My guess is that SSMS execution plan view will recommend some indexes on CreatedOn and Id. Also if the column ID is a clustered index and it is an Identity column (meaning it increments by X with every new record) then you could only apply the sort on that and it should make a big difference. This is assuming that the CreatedOn gets assigned the current datetime value at the time the record is created.

Comment: @Igor thanks for your answer!  
I cannot create any index for the view as is not schema bound (it has synonyms). And I simplified the case a little, in reality, CreatedOn is dynamic value and I have to sort by some dynamic value, then by Id.
But I do not understand why row_number() is needed for 'skip' and 'take'. Will I get different results without row_number()?

Comment: I will investigate the execution plan for the query, but nevertheless getting rid of row_number() helps

Comment: So chances are you are going to want to apply an index to CreatedOn but evaluate your execution plan first, that should be relatively easy.

Answer (score 0):

See if this is faster :

```
var result = await dbContext.Entity
    .OrderByDescending(e => e.CreatedOn)
    .ThenByDescending(e => e.Id)
    .Select((x,i) => new {index = i, item = x})
    .GroupBy(x => x.index / itemsPerPage)
    .Select(x => x.Select(y => y.item).ToList())
    .ToListAsync();
```

Comment: I believe EF will throw an exception when using that select (with the int parameter) as it can't be translated into a SQL statement.

Comment: Isn't code working with output from entity?  Would the query work if I split it into two queries?  The first query doing the Order and the second query doing the grouping by pages?